# Asking for Ideas to Switch user_key Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

After some changes in the DB, some users got duplicated (but with different `user_key` values). When users try to login, they login to the account with new `user_key` value, and therefore don't see any history of the account.

In the table everything looks like this:

```
user_key                            username    lower_username
--------------------------------    --------    --------------
8ad7d2d65d424a40015d424b57500107    mtamu       mtamu         <- duplicated user
8ada96025245dad801535faba00d016e    mtamu       NULL          <- old user
```

I tried to copy the old user `user_key` value but got an error:

```
UPDATE user_mapping
SET user_key = '8ada96025245dad801535faba00d016e' WHERE user_key = '8ad7d2d65d424a40015d424b57500107'
```

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__user_map__E1CC8CC0049C3729'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.user_mapping'. The
>   duplicate key value is (8ada96025245dad801535faba00d016e).

I tried another idea with no luck:

```
UPDATE user_mapping
SET user_key = '1' WHERE user_key = '8ada96025245dad801535faba00d016e'

UPDATE user_mapping
SET user_key = '8ada96025245dad801535faba00d016e' WHERE user_key = '8ad7d2d65d424a40015d424b57500107'
```

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_CONTENT_LABEL_OWNER". The conflict occurred in database
>   "confluence5_8_18", table "dbo.CONTENT_LABEL", column 'OWNER'.

I'm asking for ideas how to get users to login to their old accounts.

Comment: just delete the duplicate...

Comment: What DBMS?  (Looks like SQL Server)

Comment: It is SQL Server

Comment: are these the only columns in that table?

Comment: Yes, the only columns. But there are more tables.

If I delete the duplicate row from user_mapping, what about other tables that point to the new user_key?

Comment: @scsimon

DELETE FROM user_mapping WHERE user_key= '8ad7d2d65d424a40015d424b55a80034'

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_logininfo_USERNAME". The conflict occurred in database "confluence5_8_18", table "dbo.logininfo", column 'USERNAME'.

Comment: Clearly your deletes aren't set up to cascade. How are users normally added and removed from the system?

Comment: @scsimon

Users are added and removed from the system via UI registration form. When a user is deleted and recreated with the same username, all history data is mapped back to the user. But now when the user is recreated it is assigned the new user_key...

Answer (score 0):

If there are no delete cascade, just `DELETE` the value to replace.
Then `UPDATE` the one to change as the new value.

If there are conflicts with a referenced `FOREIGN KEY`,
just remove the constraints before doing the `DELETE`.

Just make sure afterwards, that no `FOREIGN KEY` references the key `@wrongValue`,
if it is so, you should `UPDATE` also the foreign columns to the new value.

```
DECLARE @normalValue as varchar(max);
DECLARE @wrongValue as varchar(max);
SET @normalValue = '8ada96025245dad801535faba00d016e';
SET @wrongValue = '8ad7d2d65d424a40015d424b57500107';

IF (SELECT COUNT(user_key) FROM user_mapping WHERE user_key = @wrongValue) > 0
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE user_mapping NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

  DELETE user_mapping
  WHERE user_key = @normalValue;

  UPDATE user_mapping
  SET user_key = @normalValue
  WHERE user_key = @wrongValue;

  ALTER TABLE user_mapping CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

  UPDATE dbo.CONTENT_LABEL
  SET Owner = @normalValue
  WHERE Owner = @wrongValue;
END
```